# Connecting Azure Active Directory with .NET Web Api, authenticated is always false

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I am developing a Standard .NET Web Api 2 with Angular 7 and I need to connect Azure Active Directory.

I have added this code:

```
public static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
       app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = configurationManager.AadTenant,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidAudience = configurationManager.AadAudience,
                    },
                });
 }
```

Both my Tenant and Audience are correct. Everything works fine and the token is valid and exists in the request.

The problem is that IsAuthenticated is always false and when I looked inside the claims in the identity they were empty

```
 protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
 {
     return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext); // Always false
 }
```

I don't know where the problem is. I have tried many links but none of them worked for me. Anybody knows why? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To protect your service, you can use IsAuthorize filter implementation something like below:

```
private static string trustedCallerClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TrustedCallerClientId"];  
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)  
        {  
            bool isAuthenticated = false;  
            try  
            {  
                string currentCallerClientId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("appid").Value;  
                isAuthenticated = currentCallerClientId == trustedCallerClientId;  
            }  
            catch (Exception ex)  
            {  
                new CustomLogger().LogError(ex, "Invalid User");  
                isAuthenticated = false;  
            }  
            return isAuthenticated;  
        }
```

The principal is not taken from the current thread, but from the actionContext. So, what you must set is the principal in the request context of the action context:

```
actionContext.RequestContext.Principal = yourPrincipal;
```

I am assuming your action context.requestcontext does not have the right data, that''s why even though your request are succeeding but your attribute is always false.

Reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-active-directory-authentication/

Hope it helps.